# Is the length function associated with the twist parameter an increasing function?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

Let $S$ be a closed hyperbolic surface and $x$ be an oriented simple closed curve in $S$. Let $y$ be an oriented closed curve  such that the geometric intersection number between $x$ and $y$ is positive. Consider a pants decomposition containing $x$. Consider the Fenchel-Nielsen coordinate of the Teichmuller space with respect to this pants decomposition. Let $l_{\chi_s}(y)$ denote the length function of $y$ with respect to the left hand side twist parameter $s$, associated to the the curve $x$. It seems that there exist a $s_0$ such that $l_{\chi_s}(b)$ is an increasing function for $s>s_0$. Is this true? If yes, what is the proof?

Thanks in advance.

PS 1: I know that the function $l_{\chi_s}(b)$ is strictly convex.

Comment: Suppose that you have an unbounded convex function defined on the set of nonnegative numbers...

Comment: @Misha Why the function is unbounded? Again intuitively  its clear but I can't prove  it. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is shown in Kerckhoff's paper: 
The Nielsen Realization Problem
Steven P. Kerckhoff
Annals of Mathematics
Second Series, Vol. 117, No. 2 (Mar., 1983), pp. 235-265

Proposition 3.5